# Moving an element with specific value to the end of dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

**Original Array**

```
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['m_unseen'] = 1;
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['user_id'] = 234;
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['id'] = 133;
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['last_updated'] = date();
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['user']['unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['user']['id'] = 234;

 $sonuc['rec'][1]['m_unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['user_id'] = 234;
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['id'] = 134;
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['last_updated'] = date();
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['user']['unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['user']['id'] = 234;

 $sonuc['rec'][2]['m_unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['user_id'] = 234;
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['id'] = 135;
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['last_updated'] = date();
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['user']['unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['user']['id'] = 234;

 $sonuc['rec'][3]['m_unseen'] = 1;
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['user_id'] = 234;
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['id'] = 136;
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['last_updated'] = date();
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['user']['unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['user']['id'] = 234;
```

**Expected Result**

```
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['m_unseen'] = 1;
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['user_id'] = 234;
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['id'] = 133;
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['last_updated'] = date();
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['user']['unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['user']['id'] = 234;

 $sonuc['rec'][1]['m_unseen'] = 1;
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['user_id'] = 234;
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['id'] = 136;
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['last_updated'] = date();
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['user']['unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['user']['id'] = 234;

 $sonuc['rec'][2]['m_unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['user_id'] = 234;
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['id'] = 134;
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['last_updated'] = date();
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['user']['unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['user']['id'] = 234;

 $sonuc['rec'][3]['m_unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['user_id'] = 234;
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['id'] = 135;
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['last_updated'] = date();
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['user']['unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['user']['id'] = 234;
```

I am trying to move all elements with **m_unseen** value is 0 to the end of the array.

I tried but couldn't get the expected result

```
function moveElement(&$array, $a, $b) {
    $out = array_splice($array, $a, 1);
    array_splice($array, $b, 0, $out);
}

    $keys = array_keys(array_column($sonuc['rec'], 'm_unseen'), 0);

     foreach ($keys as $key) {

         moveElement($sonuc['rec'], $key, $say);

     }
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is in your `moveElement` function?

Comment: I suspect you won't need sorting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`usort` with custom sort function is enough:

```
usort($sonuc['rec'], function($a, $b) {
    return 1 == $a['m_unseen'] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function with a custom callback to do the trick
This function takes two argument, the array ( passed by reference )  and a callback with two element. You compare the two element in the callback.

Here, we've simply subtract one "m_unseen" to the other since they are numbers. If it was another type, we would need to return a positive or negative integer, or 0 if they are equals, since that's what the usort function expect.

```
<?php
 $sonuc = array();
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['m_unseen'] = 1;
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['user_id'] = 234;
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['id'] = 133;
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['last_updated'] = date(1584796457);
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['user']['unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][0]['user']['id'] = 234;

 $sonuc['rec'][1]['m_unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['user_id'] = 234;
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['id'] = 134;
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['last_updated'] = date(1584796457);
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['user']['unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][1]['user']['id'] = 234;

 $sonuc['rec'][2]['m_unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['user_id'] = 234;
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['id'] = 135;
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['last_updated'] = date(1584796457);
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['user']['unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][2]['user']['id'] = 234;

 $sonuc['rec'][3]['m_unseen'] = 1;
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['user_id'] = 234;
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['id'] = 136;
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['last_updated'] = date(1584796457);
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['user']['unseen'] = 0;
 $sonuc['rec'][3]['user']['id'] = 234;

usort($sonuc['rec'], function($a, $b) {
    // switching the variable here would order the array ASC rather than DSC.
    return $b['m_unseen'] - $a['m_unseen'];
 });

 var_dump($sonuc);
```

[Here is a sandbox for you to test it out](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/347268a7e28f0aff59e2873cadc1fb141468a42a)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move the `m_unseen` with non zero values to the front, swapping zero values to the back with the help of a pointer variable.

```
<?php

$ptr = 0;

foreach($sonuc['rec'] as $key => $value){
 if($value['m_unseen'] != 0){
    $temp = $sonuc['rec'][$ptr];
    $sonuc['rec'][$ptr++] = $value;
    $sonuc['rec'][$key] = $temp;
 }
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/o1c5R